# Empirical estimation of conditional distribution $Y|X$ at the boundaries of X

Tags: estimation, conditional-probability, kernel-smoothing, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I want to estimate conditional distributions of Y | X. Where X contains several continuous covariates.

I'm coding in R. I tried several methods so far, but none gives me entirely satisfactory results when tried on simulations.
The two best methods are:

- **npcdist** from the library(np). It is based on Li and Racine (2008) non-parametric conditional distribution estimation. The results are mostly good BUT, it performs super poorly at the **boundaries of X** (as one could expect because the kernel is obviously not so good there).
  I know that you have other package to correct for density estimation at the boundaries (by reflection for example). Any idea if something like that exists for conditional density/distribution estimation?
- By estimation the **conditional quantiles** instead. Using either **npqr** from **quantreg.nonpar** or **gcrq** from **quantregGrowth**(to avoid crossing of the quantiles). Both these methods work super well, even at the boundaries, with **one** main **continuous covariate**. As they estimate non-parametrically the effect of this regressor.
  But when you have several continuous covariates the problem at the boundaries appear, as in npcdist.
  I tried to add splines, polynomials in the other regressors, nothing gives me good results.
- I also tried mixtures of normals. But it was worse than both methods mentioned above.

Is there any better alternative that I missed? I've been searching for several days and it seems that I exhausted all the possibilities out there. But maybe I missed something, hence my question.

Comment: Your question is unclear: what are you coding in `R`? Can you manage an arbitrary number of simulations from the conditional for a given value of the conditioning variate $X$?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'm coding the estimation of the conditional distribution in R.  
And for your second question, yes I can. I know the 'true' distribution for any $X=x$ (and that's why I know my estimations are not so great at the boundaries).